# css3 : how to set a backgroundcolor on a label whose radio is checked?

Tags: css

My goal is to set a background color on a label whose radio is checked

```css
label + input[type="radio"]:checked{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
          <label class="btn btn-default   ">
            <input type="radio" data-username="" name="options" id="radioPerformer" checked>All 
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default hidden" >
            <input type="radio" name="options"  id="radioDJ"> DJ <span id="spanDJ"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default hidden">
            <input type="radio" name="options"  id="radioManager"> Manager <span id="spanAdmin"></span>
          </label>
```

I tried with:

```
label + input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color:red;
}
```

with no sucess.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
          <input type="radio" data-username="" name="options" id="radioPerformer" checked><label class="btn btn-default   ">
            All 
          </label>
          <input type="radio" name="options"  id="radioDJ"><label class="btn btn-default hidden" >
             DJ <span id="spanDJ"></span>
          </label>
           <input type="radio" name="options"  id="radioManager"><label class="btn btn-default hidden">
            Manager <span id="spanAdmin"></span>
          </label>
```

Comment: Problem is that you changed the HTML !

Comment: if you have the possibility to use JS you could select it trough `document.querySelector('input[name=nameOfradio][checked]'); and then style it inline

Comment: @yarek It can not be done in CSS only unless you change the HTML

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors (at least up to level 3) can only affect things in tree order, either descendants, siblings or descendants of siblings. There is no "parent node" combinator.
Level 4 may eventually have what you need, but browsers don't implement that right now.

So to achieve what you want you will have to place the labels after their corresponding inputs and use sibling selectors to achieve your goal.